# Having trouble animating my player character, and other animated objects

Tags: java, animation, timer, slick

Before I start, here is my UML diagram:

[image: UML diagram]

I'm trying to animate my player's character, of a gif but split into 5 separate png files. I'd rather work when the 5 frames directly because it's not a detailed image, just an 8-bit character sprite. Also, don't know how to use many Photo editing software, so I'm using the separate files themselves.

I've tried quite a few examples off Stack Overflow and other tutorials but nothing seems to match what I'm trying to do on the framework I have to build for my game. It's for an end of semester project but I'm planning to build upon in after the due date and keep it open source.

Here is some of my code.

Driver. Loads the game loop and other functions.

```
package cactus;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Driver extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Thread t;
    private boolean running;

    private Controller controller;

    public Driver() {
        controller = new Controller();

        /*--- Add Game Objects ---------------------------------------*/
        controller.addObject(new Travis(500, 675, ID.Travis));
        /*------------------------------------------------------------*/

    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            t.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running) {
                render();
            }
            frames++;
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS:" + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {
        controller.tick();
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy buffer = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (buffer == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(background.getCurrentBG(), 0, 0, Frame.getWidth(), Frame.getHeight(), null);
        controller.render(g);
        g.dispose();
        buffer.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver();
    }
}
```

Controller. Loops through game objects to execute some of their render functions, which displays what they look like, and their tick functions which controls their locations and some future actions.

```
package cactus;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Controller {
    LinkedList<Objects> gameObj = new LinkedList<Objects>();

    public void tick() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObj.size(); i++) {
            Objects currentObject = gameObj.get(i);

            if (currentObject.getId() == ID.ShootFire && currentObject.getX() > Frame.getWidth() + 30) {
                removeObject(currentObject);
                System.out.println("Fire Object Removed");
            }
            currentObject.tick();
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObj.size(); i++) {
            Objects currentObject = gameObj.get(i);

            currentObject.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void addObject(Objects o) {
        this.gameObj.add(o);
    }

    public void removeObject(Objects o) {
        this.gameObj.remove(o);
    }
}
```

Player class. Gets methods from Abstract Objects class

```
package cactus;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
// import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Travis extends Objects implements ActionListener{
    ArrayList<BufferedImage> animation;
    // Timer animationTimer;
    Graphics g;
    // int i = 0;

    public Travis(int x, int y, ID id) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.animation = createAnimation();
        // this.animationTimer = createTimer(animationTimer);

        // animationTimer.start();
    }

    private synchronized ArrayList<BufferedImage> createAnimation() {
        animation = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            try {
                animation.add(ImageIO.read(new File("./src/resources/image/travis/frame_" + i + ".png")));
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); System.exit(0);}
        }
        return animation;
    }

//  private synchronized Timer createTimer(Timer animationTimer) {
//      animationTimer = new Timer(15, this);
//      animationTimer.setDelay(15*1000);
//      return animationTimer;
//  }


    @Override
    public void tick() {
        x += velocityX;
    }

    /* 
     * drawImage(img, posX, posY, observe [null])
     * 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see cactus.GameObjects#render(java.awt.Graphics)
     */
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) { 
              for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        g.drawImage(animation.get(i), x, y, null);
              }
              if (i == 6)
                  i = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

I want each object of the ArrayList (although likely will change it to Map), to play with different delays between frames.
* frame_0: 1s
* frame_1: 2s
* frame_2: 2s
* frame_3: 1s
* frame_4: 2s
* frame_5: 5s

I've tried using Timer and some other things and I'm not able to animate it, it just displays the last frame.

I don't have enough rep to post photographs.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point here the `Travis::render` method draws all 6 images every time it is invoked, so you will only ever see the last image? You need some sort of *current frame* counter that is incremented every time the controller invokes `render`.  As a clue the code `if (i == 6)
                  i = 0;` does absolutely nothing since the loop variable is out of scope after the method finishes.

Comment: @stridecolossus Hi, I had tried that and while it does animate the character, it does it almost 60 times a second so it looks like my game character is having a seizure. I need know how I can apply something, possibly Timer, to delay the animation so it shows the same frame multiple times before going onto the next one. Preferably with a set delay between frames like 0.1 seconds, 0.5 seconds, etc. Also why am I getting downvoted? I did my best to write a well written post. I don't get this website.

Comment: (Coming in from your now deleted question). Don't worry about the odd downvote. It looks like you got an upvote here too, so that should cancel it out. I was going to post [my discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) on your other post, so I will add it here. It is perhaps a bit philosophical, but it describes how a question is received is partly a product of the language used to present it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to yield the rendering thread by sleeping it for a few milliseconds between frames:

```
private static final long PERIOD = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
...

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(running) {
    // Perform frame
    ...

    // Wait for next frame
    now += PERIOD;
    final long duration = now - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(duration > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(duration);
    }
}
```

where `FRAMES_PER_SECOND` is the desired number of frames-per-second.

You could also add a counter to calculate the frame-rate if required.

There are lots of other (and better) ways of creating a render loop but this should do as a starter.

Comment: I already have a function like that sort of set up in the driver class, but the use of Thread.sleep can hold up the rest of my program. I read it was bad practice to use multithreadding while I've also seen that it's totally fine but I'm not sure what to use. Im more looking into something that will locally loop through 5 images with delay inbetween them in my Player Class

Comment: I'm not sure what you've been reading but sleeping a thread does not "hold up the rest of the program". Also multi-threading isn't "bad practice", but it is difficult to implement and easy to do badly, and therefore should be used sparingly and with care. If you're wary of using threads then perhaps use a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)?